# IllegalStateException : Activity has been destroyed . I created fragment manager in adapter class on click view

Tags: android-fragments, commit, fragmentmanager

I created recycler view and perform onclick action to get fragment view. when I click on item it should show same data in fragment so I created an on click listener in Adapter class(onBindViewHolder).

```java
package com.example.

public class Adapter extends 
RecyclerView. Adapter<ChannelAdapter.ChannelViewHolder>  {

    private final Context context;
    private List<ChannelMode> ;

    public Channel Adapter(Context context, List<ChannelModel> channelList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.channelList = channelList;
    }

    @Override
    public ChannelViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_view, parent, false);
        return new ChannelViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ChannelViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final ChannelModel channelModel = channelList.get(position);
        holder.channel_name.setText(channelModel.getChannel_name());
        holder.description.setText(channelModel.getDescription());
        Picasso.get().load(channelModel.getLogo()).into(holder.logo);
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Fragment fragment = new FragmentView();
                AppCompatActivity activity = new AppCompatActivity();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.framelayout, fragment).addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return channelList.size();
    }

    public class ChannelViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView logo;
        TextView channel_name;
        TextView description;

        public ChannelViewHolder(@NonNull final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            logo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            channel_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDesc);
            }
        }
    }
```

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/framelayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/recyclerView" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Fragment view when I click on recyclerview item.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. When we don't understand the problem there won't be a good answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Getting exception in fragmenttransaction.commit().